How to set one Cloudwatch alarm for monitoring CPU Utilization of multiple EC2 instance if they are using same tag (e.g.Name:IT_EC2)
I recently started working on AWS. I have few EC2 instances with tag (Name:Value pair as Name:IT_EC2) and want to monitor CPU Utilization.
I tried adding the metric in alarm but it only let's me add one EC2 instance ID. Our DevOps team say they change EC2 instance IDs as a part of their CLoudFormation template, but they keep the tag same.So only way for me is to create only one alarm is based on tag.
Few articles talk about accomplishing this using math expression within alarm or using lambda or CLI, but I can't figure out how. Can anyone provide some guidance, so we don't have to create multiple alarms?

I suspect you'll need a scheduled AWS Lambda function that fetches metrics from instances with that Tag, and then publish a Custom Metric.
You'll need to figure out whether you want the Average of the metric across those instances, or perhaps the Max() to warn you when even a single instance exceeds a threshold.
An alternative approach would be to have the instances in an Auto-Scaling group, which automatically generates metrics based on the whole group (eg Average CPU). The assumption with Auto-Scaling groups is that all instances are the same and are doing the same thing -- this might not be the case with your instances.

Thank you for your valuable information!! I will look into it more.
